# How to pass data through middlewares using Loopback?

Tags: node.js, middleware, strongloop, loopback

I'm actually using loopback, and here is my needs:

I have two middlewares triggered by a `POST` request on `/api/Orders/`, and I need `middleware 1` to pass data to `middleware 2`.

For example:

`middleware1.js`

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function firstMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        var toPass= "string to pass to second middleware";
        next();
  };
}
```

`middleware2.js`

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function secondMiddleware(req, res, next) {
     //Do whatever to get passed value from middleware1
  };
}
```

I did not found anything useful in the official documentation talking about this, but I may have missed it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `middleware1` you can update `req` object and access the variable in the `middleware2`.

middleware1.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function firstMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        var toPass= "string to pass to second middleware";
        req.locals = { toPass };
        next();
  };
}
```

middleware2.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    return function secondMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.locals.toPass);
    next();
  };
}
```

Comment: That's the way I wanted to do it but I thought there was a special way included in Loopback.

Thanks, Uzumaki-kun.